# Cannot install pyomo extras, anybody got the same problem?

Tags: pyomo

I am new to `pyomo` and tried to `install-extras`. I got the following error:

```
 C:\Users\ip12\AppData\Local>pyomo install-extras
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\subprocess\processmngr.py", line 631, in run_command
shell=shell)
 File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\subprocess\processmngr.py", line 776, in __init__
shell=shell)
File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
 File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
 File "C:\Users\ip12\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyomo.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
 File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\pyomo_main.py", line 82, in main
retval = _options.func(_options)
 File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\driver_help.py", line 46, in install_extras_exec
pyutilib.subprocess.run(command, tee=True)
 File "c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\subprocess\processmngr.py", line 660, in run_command
(' '.join(_cmd), err))
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Could not execute the command: 'c:\users\ip12\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\get_pyomo_extras'
    Error message: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Anaconda, you should open the conda terminal ("Environments" > "base (root)" > "open terminal") and execute that in a shell:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo.extras
```

Check the install documentation:
http://www.pyomo.org/installation